# A question based on quadratic forms in linear algebra ( rank, representation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

This particular question was asked in masters of mathematics exam of a university and I am unable to solve it. So I am asking it here.

Consider the quadratic form $Q(v)=v^{t} A v$, where
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\quad v=(x, y, z, w)$$

Then

1. $Q$ has rank 3 .
2. $x y+z^{2}=Q(P v)$ for some invertible $4 \times 4$ real matrix $P$
3. $x y+y^{2}+z^{2}=Q(P v)$ for some invertible $4 \times 4$ real matrix $P$.
4. $x^{2}+y^{2}-z w=Q(P v)$ for some invertible $4 \times 4$ real matrix $P$.

---

> Attempt: Determinant of $D_{1} $ =1 , $D_{2}$ = 1 , $D_{3}$ =-1 for some matrix and $D_{4}$ = -1 . So matrix is neither positive definite nor negative definite.

Also, I have read everything about quadratic forms from wikipedia as quadratic forms were not covered in my linear algebra class.

So, can anyone please tell how to solve this question.

> Can anyone please tell any textbook of linear algebra which covers quadratic forms in detail?

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: Is this an MCQ?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "$O$ has rank $3$" in that first choice.

Comment: *"Can anyone please tell any textbook of linear algebra which covers quadratic forms in detail?"*  -- if you know a little group theory, I'd highly recommend the Bilinear Forms chapter in Artin's Algebra.  And the chapter that follows on Linear Groups also nicely reinforces these ideas.  (For fields not of characteristic 2, there's an easy mapping between bilinear forms and quadratic forms)

Comment: [_Linear Algebra_](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/linear-algebra-9780198502371?cc=de&lang=en&) by Kaye and Wilson has a clear, hands-on introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving these questions (i.e. the classification of quadratic forms up to a change of basis) amounts to using [Sylvester's law of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

In particular, we find that $A$ has $3$ positive eigenvalues and $1$ negative eigenvalue, so its indices of innertia are $n_+ = 3, n_- = 1, n_0 = 0$.

With that, we can eliminate both choices $2,3$ bescause the symmetric matrix corresponding to these bilinear forms fails to be invertible, which means that they have zero-inex $n_0 > 0$. Choice $4$ is correct because the corresponding symmetric matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&-1&0}
$$
also has $3$ positive eigenvalues and $1$ negative eigenvalue. In fact, in this case it is possible to find a simple (diagonal!) change of basis matrix $P$.

---

The key to finding the matrix associated with a quadratic form is to note that for a $4 \times 4$ symmetric matrix $A$, we have
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc} v^TAv= &&  a_{1,1}x^2& + & a_{1,2}xy & + & a_{1,3}xz & + & a_{1,4}xw\\ 
&+&a_{2,1}xy& + & a_{2,2}y^2 & + & a_{2,3}yz & + & a_{2,4}yw\\ 
&+&a_{3,1}xz& + & a_{3,2}yz & + & a_{3,3}z^2 & + & a_{3,4}zw\\ 
&+&a_{4,1}xw& + & a_{4,2}yw & + & a_{4,3}zw & + & a_{4,4}w^2
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \phantom{v^TAv}= &&  a_{1,1}x^2& + & 2a_{1,2}xy & + & 2a_{1,3}xz & + & 2a_{1,4}xw\\ 
&&& + & a_{2,2}y^2 & + & 2a_{2,3}yz & + & 2a_{2,4}yw\\ 
&&&&& + & a_{3,3}z^2 & + & 2a_{3,4}zw\\ 
&&&&&&&+& a_{4,4}w^2.
\end{array}
$$
Now, the quadratic form from option $2$ can be written as
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}  v^TAv = &  0 x^2& + & 1\,xy & + & 0xz & + & 0xw\\ 
&& + & 0y^2 & + & 0yz & + & 0yw\\ 
&&&& + & 1\,z^2 & + & 0zw\\ 
&&&&&&+& 0w^2.
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Grossman can you please tell how you found out symmetric matrix corresponding to option 2 or 3 ? I am not able to understand that most probably because I dont know how its computed .Any help you give would be really useful

Comment: @User See my latest edit. Also, note that referring to somebody using only their last name is often considered rude.

Comment: I swear that  I wrote "Ben Grossman " instead of Grossman but it sometimes happens (as i have noted ) that site   takes command Firstname only if someone make a mistake while writing lastname and unfortunately I forgot to wrote a last n in your surname "Grossmann" . Maybe, my observation is wrong ,and that happened due  to any other reason  but as far as i remember i wrote Ben grossman . But certainly , I beg your pardon and offer my sincerest apologies to you . I didnt meant to hurt your feelings . I am really sorry!!  Beleive me ,What happened was completely unintentional .

Comment: @User That's ok, it was clear you had no intention of being offensive, even if shortening my name were intentional

Comment: @User Let me know if anything is still unclear regarding your question

Comment: @Bern Grossmann Hi!! Mr. Ben I was trying some exercise and need your little help. I was trying some exercise and there they have an answer that $Q(x, y) = x^2 +2xy +y^2$ . I think it's rank is 2 and maxtrix is a_11=a_22 = 1 and a_21=a_1/2 =1/3 . But answer is rank is 1 ? Is answer wrong ?

Comment: @User You should find that $a_{12} = a_{21} = 1$.

Comment: thank you it was stupid mistake!!